# XQuery assertion failure for SOAP UI

Tags: soap, xquery, soapui

I have been following this example:

[https://bharathsharesinfo.wordpress.com/2013/03/16/assertions-xquery-match/](https://bharathsharesinfo.wordpress.com/2013/03/16/assertions-xquery-match/://)

I have imported the wsdl file as per:

http://www.restfulwebservices.net/wcf/StockQuoteService.svc?wsdl

I have generated a MockService for the response and added a test case for the operation GetStockQuote. I have then added the XQuery Match assertion as follows (the declarations were added automatically):

```
declare namespace soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
declare namespace ns1='http://www.restfulwebservices.net/DataContracts/2008/01';
declare namespace ns='http://www.restfulwebservices.net/ServiceContracts/2008/01';
    <Result>
    {
    for $x in //ns1:GetStockQuoteResult[1]
    return <Symbol>{data($x/a:Symbol/text())}</Symbol>
    }
    </Result>
```

I am returned with the following error:

```
XQuery Match Assertion failed for path [declare namespace ns1='http://www.restfulwebservices.net/DataContracts/2008/01'; declare namespace ns='http://www.restfulwebservices.net/ServiceContracts/2008/01';   { for $x in //ns1:GetStockQuoteResult[1] return  {data($x/a:Symbol/text())}  }  ] : RuntimeException:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

As @wst correctly answer the `a` namespace prefix is missing; if you see the *SOAPUI* error log you will see:

```
  XPST0081: XQuery static error in #...<Symbol>{data($x/a:Symbol/text#:
    Prefix a has not been declared
```

Of course a solution is to simple declare the namespace `a` in your *XQuery* but
there is another option; in SOAPUI you can use `*` wildcard to reference any namespace, so your *XQuery Assertion* could be simplified to:

```
<Result>
{
for $x in //*:GetStockQuoteResult[1]
return <Symbol>{data($x/*:Symbol/text())}</Symbol>
}
</Result>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your XPath, you reference `a:Symbol`, but the namespace prefix `a` is not declared and assigned to a namespace.